# BigQuery: Returning Records for a list of specific customers

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a list of `CustomerId` in an Excel sheet that I want to use as a filter in BigQuery.

For example:

```
SELECT CustomerId, Status, OrderTotal, StoreCode, PaymentAmount FROM Orders
WHERE OrderPlacedTime > '2022-01-01'
AND CustomerId = '1,2,3 ... 1000'
```

Is there an easier way to input all these `CustomerId` values? Or do I need to transpose the IDs and separate them with a comma in order for the query to run?

Comment: You could load those `CustomerId` records into their own table and then `INNER JOIN` on it to apply the filter

Answer (score 0):

Use below as a direction

```
SELECT CustomerId, Status, OrderTotal, StoreCode, PaymentAmount 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderPlacedTime > '2022-01-01' 
AND '' || CustomerId IN UNNEST(SPLIT('1,2,3 ... 1000'))
```